# Magento 2 Block not overriding

Tags: magento2, category, overrides

I'm trying to override the Topmenu Block from Catalog module, that particular class is not getting called at all.

This is the code I wrote:

**app\code\HBBatteries\Topmenu\registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'HBBatteries_Topmenu',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app\code\HBBatteries\Topmenu\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="HBBatteries_Topmenu" setup_version="2.2.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

**app\code\HBBatteries\Topmenu\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" type="HBBatteries\Topmenu\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" /> 
</config>
```

**app\code\HBBatteries\Topmenu\Plugin\Block\Topmenu.php**

```
<?php

namespace HBBatteries\Topmenu\Plugin\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu
{

/**
 * Convert category to array
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $currentCategory
 * @return array
 */
/*This is not getting called !!!*/
private function getCategoryAsArray($category, $currentCategory)
{  
    return [
        'name' => $category->getName(),
        'id' => 'category-node-' . $category->getId(),
        'url' => $this->catalogCategory->getCategoryUrl($category),
        'has_active' => in_array((string)$category->getId(), explode('/', $currentCategory->getPath()), true),
        'is_active' => $category->getId() == $currentCategory->getId()
    ];
    }

}
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: after overriding have done setup:upgrade & compile ?

Answer (score 1):

enter code here`You have to add only following lines of code in di.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" type="HBBatteries\Topmenu\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" /> 
</config>
```

Comment: have updated the code, but still core Block is getting called

Answer (score 0):

If **preference** is not working, try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="custom_topmenu" type="HBBatteries\Topmenu\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

make sure the filepaths are correct.